# Firestore returning out of function and not appending any objects to array

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

For some reason when i add the code `if user.uid == uid {return}`
   it will return out of the function altogether and not add any users to the array even though i only want to filter out the current user from being added to the array?

```
func fireStoreFetchUsers(){
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("Users")
       .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

          if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
          } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let dictionary = document.data()
                let user = User2(uid: "", distanceFrom: "any", dictionary: dictionary)

                if user.uid == uid {return}

                self.users.append(user)               
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what `return` means. It sounds like you want to `continue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem in summary is that you want to skip a specific element of the array you are iterating through. This is exactly what `continue` does, so just change `return` to `continue`.

After the above change, the last two lines of the loop won't be executed when `user.uid == uid` and hence that specific user won't be added to the `users` array and the `collectionView` won't be reloaded, but the loop will continue its iteration with the next element rather than returning from the function.

```
for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
    let dictionary = document.data()
    let user = User2(uid: "", distanceFrom: "any", dictionary: dictionary)

    if user.uid == uid {continue}

    self.users.append(user)               
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks David works as you know, has this always been like this as i swear the return code worked before i updated to the new firestore database?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, there was no change in the behaviour of [Control Transfer Statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID135) since Swift was introduced.